Storage Permission Not Working in Flutter App
I am developing a Flutter app that requires storage permissions. I am using the permission_handler package to request these permissions. However, when I try to request the storage permissions, the app directs me to the settings page with "No Permission Required" displayed, even though I have declared the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Code: Here’s my main Dart code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            PermissionStatus storagePermission =
                await Permission.storage.request();
            if (storagePermission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
              print("granted");
            }
            if (storagePermission == PermissionStatus.denied) {
              print("permission denied");
            }
            if (storagePermission == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
              openAppSettings();
            }
          },
          child: Text('Ask Permission'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


And here are the permissions I have declared in my AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

What I’ve Tried:
I have ensured that I imported the permission_handler package correctly.
I have run flutter clean and flutter pub get multiple times.
I followed several YouTube tutorials, but none resolved the issue.
I even created a new project from scratch to see if the problem persisted.
Expected Behavior: I expect that when I click the "Ask Permission" button, the app should request storage permissions.
Actual Behavior: Instead of requesting permissions, the app redirects me to the settings page where it displays "No Permission Required"
settings page

When the storage permission is permanently denied, the application will direct the user to the settings page:
if (storagePermission == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
  openAppSettings();
}

If the user denies permission multiple times, the permission status will change to "permanently denied." At this point, the user must manually enable the permission from the app's settings page. If you remove the openAppSettings() line, the app won't be able to navigate to the settings page when the permission is denied.
Note that if the user cancels the permission request multiple times, the permission dialog will no longer be shown. However, reinstalling the app will reset the permission state, allowing the dialog to appear again.
